# How to create own font with emojis included (Maybe with Fontforge, Python)?

Tags: python, fonts, emoji, truetype, fontforge

I want to create my own .ttf font.
It should contains emojis.

I have some Images (emojis) and I want to put these in a new font (I don't want to edit an existing font and I don't have an empty .ttf template).

I googled and found out that it is possible with python (I am happy about this because Python is my favorite programming language and, in my opinion, I am good in it) and fontforge.

I already installed fontforge but I can't import it in python.

and I don't know how to continue after Import.

can someone give me an example please.

or do you know another way to do this, It don't have to be python and fontforge.
but please with example.

Thank you soooo much

Answer (score 1):

Since you like using Python, FontTools might be useful for you. See https://fonttools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/colorLib/index.html for documentation regarding building fonts with a COLR table. Also, https://github.com/googlefonts/picosvg and https://github.com/googlefonts/nanoemoji might be of interest.

You didn't actually mention which colour format you want to use for your emoji: bitmaps (CBDT or sbix tables), layered outlines (COLR/CPAL tables), or embedded SVG documents (SVG table)>. I know the above will work for COLR/CPAL; not sure about CBDT, sbix or SVG.

Comment: I will look into your links, thanks...

I use SVG files 512x512 Pixels,
I created some of them already and tried to do something with fontforge:

import fontforge
blank = fontforge.font()
blank.save("blank.sfd")
font = fontforge.open("blank.sfd")
glyph = font.createMappedChar("\U0000263A")
glyph.importOutlines("263A.svg")
font.generate("font.ttf")

but I get an error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 38, in <module>
    glyph = font.createMappedChar("\U0000263A")
ValueError: Glyph name, ☺, not in current encoding

and the colors doesnt work.

Comment: Sorry, I cant format my comment, I put somthing in a new answer...

Comment: Sorry, the answer was deleted by someone 